# Building urls with SessionID in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, session-state, sessionid

Is there a way to build urls for an action in-lining the SessionID in ASP.NET MVC ?

I need to build urls that will be used by others clients apps which need to download some kind of data but identifying the original session and I would like to have a self-contained url to do that.

Comment: Why not to use cookies for that purpose?

Comment: Suppose that a javascript will deliver this url to a remote client, this remote client can be a robot, it isn't a browser in the same context where the url was got. Is preferable to have the SessionID just appended as a url parameter and the webservice would be the one who manually would find the session, but why don't we leave it to IIS and ASP.NET just building a self-contained url ?